# Pythonic style for stepping through two lists and avoiding idx?

Tags: python

(Before I begin, let us presuppose this is an interview question, and I am intended to avoid merely calling sorted.)

I have this working Python code:

```
def merge_sorted_lists(left, right):
    leftlen = len(left)
    rightlen = len(right)
    leftidx = 0
    rightidx = 0
    newlist = []
    while leftidx < leftlen or rightidx < rightlen:
        if rightidx == rightlen or left[leftidx] <= right[rightidx]:
            newlist.append(left[leftidx])
            leftidx += 1
        elif leftidx == leftlen or right[rightidx] < left[leftidx]:
            newlist.append(right[rightidx])
            rightidx += 1
    return newlist
```

I'm a long time C++ programmer who has recently learned enough Python to know that this "smells" very un-Pythonic with the prolific usage of idx.  Is there a more elegant way to iterate through two lists when the advancement of the iterator needs this fine-tuned control?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is a particularly strong code smell, given the constraints (mainly that you can't use `sort` or `sorted`, which would be the *truly* Pythonic thing to do, and next-best would be to use an already-implemented mergesort from PyPI). I find manually futzing with the indices more readable and more understandable than (for example) introducing `yield`. I will say, for "classic algorithm" exercises like this, it is acceptable to use shorter names, like `i` and `j`, or `x` and `y`, etc., which actually *help* readability.

Comment: [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#l357)'s how `heapq.merge` does it. (Side note: `_len = len` is probably something they had to do for performance reasons, and shouldn't be done unless that little bit of extra performance actually matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, for a first guess, I'd start out by trying to use generators instead. And I'm using yield instead of constructing a list because a) generators can be infinite and b) hey, once you start using a generator, might as well use generators all the way down.

```
def merge(left,right): 
    left = iter(left)
    right = iter(right)
    left_val = next(left)
    right_val = next(right)
    try:
        while True:
            if left_val <= right_val:
                yield left_val
                left_val = next(left) #left.next() in python2
            else:
                yield right_val
                right_val = next(right)
    except StopIteration: #I have exhausted one of the iterators
        if left_val <= right_val:
            #left list depleted
            yield right_val
            for i in right: yield i #or use yield from right, if your python is fancy enough
        else:
            #right list depleted
            yield left_val
            for i in left: yield i
```

```
In [2]: f = merge([0,4,17],[2,4,5,6,6,6])
In [3]: list(f)
Out[3]: [0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 17]
```

Comment: I realize this is probably a much-less well-written [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge), but *mumble* practice *mumble*

Comment: I would say forcing the user to provide an iterator is unpythonic. Since `it = iter([]); it is iter(it)`, then you can just call `iter` on the arguments inside the function, and let the method throw an exception if the arguments are not iterable.

Comment: I would just do `left = iter(left)`, so that you can also pass lists or other iterable objects to the function. This is not unpythonic, and `iter(generator)` will just return the generator. The code looks mostly ok to me, but I guess it does not correctly handle the edge case when one of the generators is empty, since then it should probably still iterate over the other one.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you would like to avoid using "sorted" because you want a solution that better describes the algorithm, but I honestly think that the pythonic solution requires it.

```
def merge_sorted_lists(left,right):
    return sorted(left+right)
```

For a non-pythonic solution that exposes a reasonable algorithm without tracking indices, you could try this recursive solution:

```
def merge_sorted_lists(left,right,acc=[]):
    if not left:
        return acc + right
    if not right:
        return acc + left
    if left[0] < right[0]:
        return merge_sorted_lists(left[1:],right,acc=acc+[left[0]])
    else:
        return merge_sorted_lists(left,right[1:],acc=acc+[right[0]])
```

This one is quite a few lines longer than my other solution and long inputs could overwhelm the stack.

Comment: Small clarification comment for anyone who, like me, thought "why sort again? that must be super slow." Well, it's (probably) not, because [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) can take advantage of natural runs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe create a merge generator for that:

```
def merge_generator(llist, rlist):
    while len(llist) + len(rlist) > 0:
        if len(llist) == 0:
            yield rlist[0]
            rlist = [1:]
        elif len(rlist) == 0:
            yield llist[0]
            llist = [1:]
        else:
            if llist[0] < rlist[0]:
                yield rlist[0]
                rlist = rlist[1:]
            else:
                yield llist[0]
                llist = llist[1:]
```

It's just a skeleton though, you could probably make it much nicer, e.g. by separating the loops etc.

Comment: `rlist = [1:]` is illegal syntax, I guess you mean `rlist = rlist[1:]` instead. But this is bad coding practice, since for a list of length `n`, you are creating `n` new lists of average length `n/2`, so overall an `O(n^2)` algorithm. Merging 2 sorted lists can be done in `O(n)` by using iterators, as shown by NightShadeQueen.